# Проблема при расширении свойств класса

Tags: c#

Создаю обёртку над `SortedDictionary`.

И тут возникла здоровенная проблема при присваивании значения (`set`):

Если я пишу `this[key] = value;`, то он, логично, уходит в вечный цикл. Внутренняя переменная у `SortedDictionary` `value` приватна, и я не могу её изменять.

Можно создать свою переменную `value` и работать с ней, но тогда большинство(все) методы из `SortedDictionary` перестанут работать.

Как выбраться из сложившейся дилеммы?

```
public class myDictionary<TKey, TValue> : SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> {
    TValue tempValue;
    public TValue this[TKey key] {
        get {
            ...
        }
        set {
            if (Keys.Contains(key))
                this[key] = value;  << tyt          
            else {
                Add(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А `base[key]` не работает?

Comment: Лучше бы вы не удаляли свой предыдущий вопрос. В нём было яснее, что вам хочется. Вообще, добавлять в словарь можно просто `dict[key] = value;` - если ключа ещё нет, он создастся. А получать с помощью метода `TryGetValue`.

Comment: Что это вообще _if (Keys.Contains(key))
                this[key] = value;_  Затереть предыдущее значение ?

Comment: Логика не понятна. Если такой ключ есть if (Keys.Contains(key)), то опять воткнуть этот ключ.

Comment: @Monk сработало, спасибо. Оформите как ответ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `dict[key] = value;` я так и делал. Выбивало исключение "нет объекта с таким ключем"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе наследнике всегда можно обратиться к предку используя `base`.

В вашем случае - можно написать

```
base[key] = value;
```